# cannot allocate memory in C

Tags: c, arrays, out-of-memory

I want to define a 3D array/pointer to store my computing results:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    float ***ww;
    int i, j, k;
    int n1 = 3000, n2 = 6000, n3 = 9000;
    ww = floatalloc3(n1, n2, n3); /* floatalloc3 is a self-defined function used to allocate memory space for 3D array/pointer */
    for (i = 0; i < n1; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < n2; j++) {
            for (k = 0; k < n3; k++) {
                ww[i][j][k] = 0.0;
            }
        }
    }
    free(**ww);
    free(*ww);
    free(ww);
    return 0;
}
```

But an error pops up says `cannot allocate 648000000000 bytes: Cannot allocate memory`. So how can I solve such problem, any idea?

Is it possible to split the data and store to different cores?

Comment: what is the question? Why your program can't allocate ~648 GB of memory? You tell us.

Comment: [I think you're gonna need a bigger computer.](https://www.google.com/search?q=I+think+you%27re+gonna+need+a+bigger+boat)

Comment: ...not speaking of a fact that the error is coming from your "self-defined function", which you haven't even shown us.

Comment: OK. Sorry for the cynicism. You will probably have to redesign your program. Your data structure is too expansive.

Comment: Your usage of `free` seems to be a bit contradictory with the error message. If you tried to allocate all that memory at once, in a continuous block, that's not how you're supposed to access or free it. And "how to solve such problem": You didn't tell us the problem itself, but probably working on portions of all that data is the way to go

Comment: `ww[i][j][k]` with `ww` defined as `float ***ww;`, is not going to work anyway. C arrays are not pointers. Google that.

Comment: @Jabberwocky: with variable dimensions, the OP seems to use 2 levels of indirection to access the elements, which is somewhat inefficient and not a true 3D array but the syntax `ww[i][j][k]` is correct.

Comment: One problem here is that *even the bookkeeping for the 3rd level pointers is going to take hundreds of megabytes of space*

Answer (score 3):

You want to allocate about 3000 * 6000 * 9000 * 4 bytes of data, which is ~**648GB**, a **little** too much.

Comment: What do you mean?  Didn't Bill Gates famously say that 640G ought to be enough for anybody?

Comment: I wonder what will happen to this answer in few years (if it is not deleted..)

Comment: @EugeneSh. In fact not too far. Consumer computers with 128GB are already between us, and it's perfectly possible these days to have one with 1TB+. For instance: http://www.supermicro.com/en/products/x11/motherboards/ultra

Comment: @sidyll Yeah, I mean it will be amusing as an historical artifact. As we might laugh now at answer saying "You want to allocate 10Mb??, are you crazy?" that would would be legit for few decades ago..

Comment: Paul, *"which"*, not *"witch"*.

Answer (score 2):

The amount of memory you are trying to allocate seems humongous: 648 billion bytes plus the overhead of 2 levels of indirection! Your system probably does not let you allocate that much memory.

You should test the return value of `floatalloc3` to detect allocation failure. As a matter of fact, it would be useful to post the source code for this *self-defined* function to ascertain its correctness.

Note also that the 3 `free` calls might not be enough to free the allocated blocks, but without the source code to `floatalloc3`, one can only speculate.

Answer (score 2):

If you truly intend to compute 3000×6000×9000 floating-point values (162,000,000,000 values), you need to reconsider your approach.

There are several approaches, but the most typical is to split the task into smaller sections, and compute them one by one.

If the grid is mostly empty, but you need to access it in an unpredictable fashion (making splitting the task undesirable), you can use OS-specific methods to memory-map the dataset. (You do need a 64-bit OS to do this with this particular dataset, though; and you do also need sufficient storage on some filesystem to store the data in.) I've shown how to do this in Linux in 2011 in another forum [here](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/data-type-in-c-to-hold-tetrabyte-875026/#post4324888); this example program manipulates a terabyte-sized memory-mapped dataset, almost twice the size of the dataset OP is considering.

In any case, you definitely do not wish to use two-level indirection to access the data. This wreaks havoc with current CPU's ability to predict and cache accesses, and will lead to poor performance.  Instead, you should use a linear data structure. For example:

```
size_t  xsize;
size_t  ysize;
size_t  zsize;
float  *cells;

#define  CELL(x,y,z)  cells[(x) + xsize*( (y) + ysize * (z) )]
```

In other words, the index of each cell in the grid is `(x) + (y)*xsize + (z)*xsize*ysize`.  Not only is the data then consecutive in memory (which is important for caching), but the CPU (and your compiler) can also better predict future accesses, based on access patterns.

Comment: Sparse Matrix seems like a good choice if it's supposed to be mostly empty.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons: The number of steps along each dimension made me think of something like finding isosurfaces (equipotential surfaces) of some complicated scalar function that can only be evaluated numerically. In such cases, the grid is mostly unevaluated, and the evaluated cells are highly connected, and the memory mapping technique usually performs better than in-memory sparse matrix techniques. (I've elaborated on that in another question.)